# android - rest API timeout

Tags: android, api, rest, timeout, postman

I am developing an android application which calls http requests.
The rest API is on the same laptop (using wamp). I test the API over post man (Chrome plugin), and I get the right response after ~21s ...The strange thing is, I have received immediate answer when the api was on an other pc and other network.

I didn't change nothing on the wamp config (and I have the same version) or on the code of the rest api.
The api was written in Laravel by someone else, and worked fine on the previous laptop/server.

How could I solve this?

Comment: What do server logs say? How powerful are both computers? How fast is internet?

Comment: I've had some problems with WAMP, being so slow, i fixed it switching to Xampp, so give it a try.

Comment: server log: 192.168.0.106 - - [30/Jul/2014:15:18:25 +0300] "POST /.../login HTTP/1.1" 200 55

Comment: I just noticed that the CMS loads very slow too. I solved the issue by changing "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" in laravel/app/config/database.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that the CMS loads very slow too. I solved the issue by changing "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" in laravel/app/config/database.php